# If $A$ and $B$ have the same measure, are they isomorphic?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request

During a discussion, the following result was mentioned.

**Theorem.** Let $A$ and $B$ two Borel-measurable subsets of $\mathbb R$ with the same (positive and finite) Lebesgue measure. Then, there exists a measurable and bijective map from $A$ to $B$.

Apparently, this is well-known and "I should be able to find it in any book". However, I couldn't. Could anyone point at a reference, please? I wonder if it is (true and) easy to prove. Thanks!

Comment: Just a guess: first, find such a map from $A$ to an interval.

Comment: Good point. I agree that without loss of generality we can assume that B is an interval, but I still don't see how I would be able to do it.